# Strange result getting length of array

Tags: c

Why does this return a length of 8??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getLength(char arr[]) {
    return sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
}

char text[] = "1234567890123456789";

int main (void) {
    int i;

    int e=getLength(text);
    printf("%d\n",e);
    for (i = 0; i < e; i++) {

        printf("%c\n", text[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is asked again and again (the last time that I saw it was 3 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205730/using-array-in-function-c). A simple Google search "sizeof array wrong" immediately leads to answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because `sizeof(array)` will give you the size of the array pointer and NOT the actual size of the array itself.

Comment: This is not correct, `sizeof(array)` yields the total byte size of the array if it is not decayed to a pointer. Eg: `char array[10]; sizeof(array)`

Comment: @Jack I answered it keeping in mind the code he had posted

Answer (score 2):

because when you pass an array as an argument, it decays to a pointer. So `sizeof(arr)` yields the size of the pointer (which is 8 bytes on your architecture), not the whole size of the array.

Comment: To add to this, in C you pretty much always want to pass the length of the array to the function handling it.

Comment: @Enzo: I was going to write it but then I realized that the aim of the function was to compute the length :)

Comment: Oh oops! That's true! I'm kind of curious now: if I had allocated an array and forgotten its size, is there anyway in C to figure that out later?